# Json.net deserialize to class

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

trying to deserialize this peace of json string using json.net, but i always get exception when deserializing. Can anyone help me set up classes so that this will deserialize.

Thanks

```
{
    "type":"some_type",
    "version":"0.1",
    "data":
    {
        "item_name_1":
        {
            "id":266,
            "key":"aaa",
            "name":"aaa",
            "title":"title_1",
            "info":
            {
                "property_1":9,
                "property_2":4,
            }
        },
        "item_name_2":
        {
            "id":266,
            "key":"bbb",
            "name":"bbb",
            "title":"title_2",
            "info":
            {
                "property_1":93,
                "property_2":24,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "get exception when deserializing" Best to paste the exception message when asking such a question.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: null refence, but the main problem is how to set up classes so that it will deserialize item_name_X (can be named diferently each time they occur)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we ignore the comma, which is apparently a typo

> The problem is because item_name can be named different (item_name_1, _2...

Yes, that is entirely correct; the names need to match. If you need to map something that *doesn't* match, you'll need to *either* provide a custom converter, or (usually simpler) map the data into a dictionary - i.e. you might have:

```
public Dictionary<string, Item> data {get;set;}
```

(to represent the `"data":` node)

This will result in key-value pairs, where each key is the field name (`"item_name_1"`, etc), and each value is the `Item` instance (with properties `id`, `key`, `name`, etc).

i.e.

```
public class MyRootObject {
    public string type {get;set;}
    public string version {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string, Item> data {get;set;}
}
pulic class Item {
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string key {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string title {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string,int> info {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma(,) after the last property by `info`, this shouldn't be there.
I always use [jsonlint](http://pro.jsonlint.com/) to check if there are any errors in my json objects.

```
{
    "type":"some_type",
    "version":"0.1",
    "data":
    {
        "item_name_1":
        {
            "id":266,
            "key":"aaa",
            "name":"aaa",
            "title":"title_1",
            "info":
            {
                "property_1":9,
                "property_2":4
            }
        },
        "item_name_2":
        {
            "id":266,
            "key":"bbb",
            "name":"bbb",
            "title":"title_2",
            "info":
            {
                "property_1":93,
                "property_2":24
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a typo. Still, cant deserialize. The problem is because item_name can be named different (item_name_1, _2...)